# Is it sensible to use R 3D graph to visualize the following

Tags: r, 3d

After creating a JSON data structure and iterating over that JSON structure I came up with following Data representation. Column 1 & and Column 2 are String data type Column 4 represents sum of type explained in column 3. 
Example:

```
A | B | Level1 | 10
A | C | Level2 | 1
```

To get a verbal explanation on this I would take countries in Country A there are People who can speak country B's language at level 1 expertise and the total of them equals to 10.

I was thinking to represent this in 3 Axis, X = Country1, Y = Country2, and Z represent the levels. Is this sensible if so How can I accomplish this? I don't have prior experience with R 3D Graphics.

Here is how my actual data look like: They are in CSV file.

Here is data in a dataframe:

```
  country1 country2 langLevel frequency
1       gv       ca    level1         2
2       gv       bg    level1         1
3      zea       li    level1         1
4      zea       li    level3         1
```

I hope I explained the problem clear enough with what I want to accomplish. I was thinking and seems like 3D is the best way to represent this but I could be wrong.

Data in CSV Format:

```
country1,country2,langLevel,frequency
gv,ca,level1,2
gv,bg,level1,1
zea,li,level1,1
zea,li,level3,1
zea,de,level1,26
zea,de,level3,5
zea,el,level1,1
zea,eo,level1,3
zea,en,level1,5
zea,en,level2,34
zea,en,level3,38
zea,en,level4,12
zea,es,level1,7
zea,la,level1,7
zea,zea,level1,5
zea,zea,level3,4
zea,stq,level1,1
zea,sk,level2,1
zea,nl,level4,4
zea,fr,level2,9
zea,fy,level2,1
cdo,cdo,level3,1
cdo,de,level1,23
cdo,de,level2,4
cdo,de,level3,4
cdo,eo,level1,1
cdo,eo,level2,1
cdo,eo,level3,3
cdo,en,level1,6
cdo,en,level2,31
cdo,en,level3,38
cdo,en,level4,17
cdo,es,level1,8
cdo,es,level2,6
cdo,es,level3,3
cdo,fr,level1,14
cdo,fr,level2,11
cdo,fr,level3,6
gd,als,level1,1
gd,af,level1,2
vls,de,level1,32
vls,de,level2,7
vls,de,level3,6
vls,de,level4,3
vls,eo,level1,2
vls,eo,level2,3
vls,eo,level3,3
vls,en,level1,7
vls,en,level2,38
vls,en,level3,53
vls,en,level4,16
vls,es,level1,15
vls,es,level2,4
vls,es,level3,1
vls,es,level4,1
vls,ru,level2,8
vls,ru,level3,1
vls,ja,level1,2
```

This is what I tried but, its really had to see anything clear in this plot:

```
library("rgl")
plot3d(template_levels$country1, template_levels$country2, template_levels$frequency, col=template_levels$langLevel)
```

Here is the plot:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to use barplots with different colors. Here is a solution using package `ggplot2` and assuming that your data frame is named `df`.

On the x axis we see `country2` values then for each `country1` we have separate facet. Each bar is colored according to `langLevel`. `scales="free_y"` in `facet_grid()` ensures that we have different y scale in each facet (because values are quite different).

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(country2,frequency,fill=langLevel))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  facet_grid(country1~.,scales="free_y")
```

[image]

Comment: This is a fantastic idea than using 3D, very clear and can dive into individual country1 Vs Country2 great. After putting so much information on the question the question is mark for close. I feel this has archival value.

Comment: One issue I have is, I have more than 100 countries in Country1, and country2 what would you recommend?

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis with so many countries it will be very hard to get good representation. Maybe you can divide data in smaller parts and then plot each part.

Comment: Yes thats what actually I was planning on doing. THanks,